# Turning table data into columns and counting by frequency

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a dataframe in the following form:

[image]

shape is 2326 x 1271

Column names are just serialized from 0-1269 while rows are categories that could repeat like "apple" in the example.  The internal data points can represent anything (let's say they represent stores in this example) and I'm trying to convert them into columns and having the data points become the number of times that category shows up in that "store".  Visually, here is the table I'm trying to get to:

[image]

Note that Apple shows up in AA and RR twice

Comment: try pivot or pivot_table functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) along with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to compute the frequency counts:

**Data:**

```
index= ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwi']
data = [['AA', 'DD', 'RR', ''], ['DD', 'PP', '', ''], 
        ['AA', 'RR', 'TT', 'SS'], ['EE', 'NN', '',''], ['NN', 'WW','', '']]
frame = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=np.arange(4))
frame
```

[image]

**Operations:**

```
df = frame.stack().reset_index(0, name='values')
df = pd.crosstab(df['level_0'], df['values']).drop('', axis=1).replace(0, '')
df.index.name=None; df.columns.name=None
df
```

[image]

Comment: This might be the winner.  One question, what's happening after the ".drop (...)"? Gives me a " ' ' not contained in axis" error when I keep it but doesn't seems to work without the whole drop and rename

Comment: I think you can omit `.drop('', axis=1)` altogether. The reason it was used was because of an additional column getting created after performing the `crosstab` operation. It works fine without that too. See if it works till the `crosstab` part. Rest is for purely aesthetical purpose.