# UnicodeDecodeError Help: Data needs to be in ascii for seaborn but source code is in utf-8

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, encoding, seaborn

Context: I'm trying to build a seaborn heatmap in order to map the following type of data (in a dataframe):

[image]

(This can be up to 50 fruits and 5500 stores)

My problem (I think) is that seaborn appears to want to use ascii but my data is in utf-8. When I read the csv file, I can't do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'ascii')
```

without getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I bring it in using utf-8, it will read and I can reshape it to heatmap-friendly form but then when trying to run:

```
sns.heatmap(df2)
```

I get a similar UnicodeDecodeError

I do have simple special characters (colons, backspaces, etc.) in either my store or fruit fields so I'm wondering what the best approach is here.

- Should I run something on my dataframe to remove the utf-8 character
  then encode in ascii?
- Should I be doing something to my source .csv file to remove the utf-8 characters?
- Can I run seaborn another way to let is accept the encoding I have?

If anybody has a preferred method, can they help me with the proper code to get it done?

Python version 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)
Pandas (0.18.1)
Seaborn (0.7.1)

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3.x? Which versions of Seaborn and Pandas are you using?

Comment: Also, to clarify: You say that if you run ``sns.heatmap(df)``, you get the same UnicodeDecodeError as for your ``read_csv('data.csv', encoding='ascii')`` command. How is that dataframe ``df`` created if the ``pd.read_csv()`` command failed?

Comment: what happens when you do pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'utf8')

Comment: @Schmuddi: Edited the question to include versions.  Also I should have clarified but, the df from part 1 was brought in using the default encoding then reshaped into a heatmap-friendly format.

Comment: @Boud - works fine but then I get an error after reshaping and trying to run it through the heatmap function.  Editing question to clarify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration (Python 2.7, Pandas 0.18.1, Seaborn 0.7.1) should certainly be able to handle utf-8. Even if the font used in the plot doesn't support these unicode characters, the heatmap should still be displayed. Here is a test case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Kiwi'] * 2,
        'Store': [u'Kr\xf6ger'] * 4 + [u'F\u0254\u0254d Li\u01ebn'] * 4,
        'Stock': [6, 1, 3, 4, 1, 7, 7, 9]})

sns.heatmap(df.pivot("Fruit", "Store", "Stock"))
```

The problem, therefore, is somewhere in your data frame `df2`. Your comment states that `df2` is created by reshaping another data frame, probably also by something like `pivot()` or `crosstab()`.

Let's assume that this original data frame contains the columns `Store` and `Fruit`, and that it was read from  your file like so, i.e. with default encoding:

```
raw = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

For testing, this is the content of that file `data.csv`:

```
Store,Fruit,Stock
Kröger,Apple,6
Kröger,Banana,1
Kröger,Orange,3
Kröger,Kiwi,4
Fɔɔd Liǫn,Apple,1
Fɔɔd Liǫn,Banana,7
Fɔɔd Liǫn,Orange,7
Fɔɔd Liǫn,Kiwi,9
```

Now, in order to fix the encoding of columns `Store` and `Fruit` so that they contain valid Unicode strings, use the [`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) string method, like so:

```
raw["Store"] = raw["Store"].apply(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"))
raw["Fruit"] = raw["Fruit"].apply(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"))
```

Now, `heatmap()` should work happily with the data frame:

```
sns.heatmap(raw.pivot("Fruit", "Store", "Stock"))
```

Comment: Is there a reason that doing `df['Store'] = df['Store'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')` gives me `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)` ?

Comment: Also, you're right about the reshaping.  Specifically, I followed the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39899507/6210012

Comment: @AnjanG: ``u\xf6`` is the Unicode for ``ö``. This means that if you get this error when trying to decode the strings in ``Store``,  in all likelihood the values in that column are already valid Unicode strings. If so, what happens if you skip this command? Any success with the heatmap? I'm afraid that without a sample data file that produces your error, there's not much left that I can do to help you.